# Google Drive API and R httr GET and add_headers not consistent with url with parameters

Tags: r, google-drive-api, httr

I'm working on a project with the Google Drive API and I found an inconsistency that either has to do with the Drive API or httr's way of handling headers.

I want to get the list of files in a specific folder on Drive, and if I send a GET request using this url:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q='FOLDER_ID_HERE'+in+parents&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Everything comes back correctly. If I use the httr::GET function with httr::add_headers, however:

```
GET("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files",
    config(token=gtoken),
    add_headers("q" = "'FOLDER_ID_HERE' in parents"))
```

I end up receiving some documents that do not have that folder ID as a parent folder. What gives?

Comment: It isn't a header, its a query. Pass the full URL

Comment: It's the same for query, too. Turns out it's the quotes. If you switch double and single quotes there, it works.

Comment: Care to answer this in a "proper" answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same for query, too. Turns out it's the quotes. If you switch double and single quotes there, it works. It's a problem with Drive IDs and url escaping.